# How to extract bitmap images from .slide file generated by a CytoVision Platform

Tags: image, bitmap, extract

I am working with neural network to classify images.

I have some files generated by a CytoVision Platform. I would like to use the images in those files but I need to extract them somehow.

These .slide files contain several images of apparently 16kb each one.

I have developed a program in C that I am currently running on linux to extract each 16kb in files. I should build a header in order to use those images.

I don't know which format they have.

If I look at the entire file as a bitmap with FileAlyzer I can see this:

[File as a bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QGUr.png)

This link should allow anyone to download an example file:

https://ufile.io/2ibdq

This is what it seems to be one image header:

42 4D 31 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 9E 5F 98 D7 47 60 A1 40 01 04 4D 65 74 31 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 64 31 2E 29 B5 46 DC 40 01 04 4D 65 74 32 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 87 7D 26 70 88 C0 C5 40 01 04 4D 65 74 33 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 C8 97 53 05 BB 0D 0F 41 01 04 54 65 78 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 5C 40 07 04 54 65 78 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 40 07 04 54 65 78 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 76 40 07 04 54 65 78 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 CD 40 07 0A 43 68 72 6F 6D 73 41 72 65 61 00 00 00 00 00 4C BD 40 05 00 F3 76 84 D3 82 85 74 40 07 08 42 6F 75 6E 64 61 72 79 00 00 00 00 00 88 B3 40 05 00 D9 CE F7 53 E3 AD 7E 40 07 04 41 72 65 61 00 00 00 00 00 88 B3 40 05 00 20 EF 55 2B 13 0B 85 40 07 07 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 69 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 40 03 04 43 69 72 63 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 9D E5 51 0E 5C 34 65 40 03 03 42 47 52 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 7D 0C CE C7 E0 AC 86 40 03 04 54 65 78 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 53 40 07 04 41 52 41 54 00 00 00 00 00 40 8F 40 05 00 86 89 F7 23 A7 79 7E 40 07 05 43 6C 61 73 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 BF 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

With notepad++ I can see the previous hex like this:

BM1     @? ??G`?Met1     @? d1.)??Met2     @? ?&p?bMet3     @? ?S?ATex1      ?      @\@Tex2      ?       D@Tex3      ?      ?@Tex4      ?      ??
ChromsArea     L? ???t@Boundary     ?@ ???~@Area     ?@  ?bObjects      i@       @Circ     @? ?Q\4e@BGR     @? }??@Tex5      ?       S@ARAT     @? Ð??~@Class      ??      ??       @

Hope someone can give me an idea about the format of the images and what info I can extract from the header.

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux computer, or a Mac? Or are you stuck with Microsoft Windows? Nobody is going to want to give their Email address to download your file either - can you find a better file sharing host?

Comment: I am working with linux and programing in c. I have this other link, no registration required :) https://ufile.io/2ibdq

Comment: Do you have any references for the format of the files or have you tried contacting the manufacturer's Technical Support?

Comment: I don't have any references about the format. I have tried contacting several times the manufacturer but no answer so far.

Comment: Is the image you loaded into `FileAlyzer` the exact same one you shared on StackOverflow?

Comment: It is the same file. It contains a lot of small images which you can see with FileAlyzer, yes.